# How to initialize a string with special characters `\` in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have a string **\"Notes\":[\"**

How to initialize **\"Notes\":[\"** to a string using JAVA?

I tried `String subString1 = "\"Notes\":[";` but getting only `"Notes":[`

Comment: \ is an escape character, so you need to put \\ for every \ you want in a `String` so it can escape itself.  You will still need to escape the double quotes with a \" as well.  So \" would be \\\" instead of \".

Comment: Got it. It solved.   String subString1 = "\\\"Notes\\\":[";  is the solution.

Comment: That question is for Java. I mentioned it. At the beginning i thought, I put tag Java so it will do automatically in Java section. But later I understand, I should be more specific so that it is easily understandable. So, I changed it to Java. Dont know the same syntax works for other programming language. Thanks

Comment: @FunnyBoss This looks like JSON. If it is and that is what you are dealing with you should use a JSON library for easier usage instead of building such a string by yourself. Such an approach is too error-prone.

Comment: @ Progman it is not JSON. I have a big text file where I need to find that string and then need to extract data from that point to next new line of that file. So, I have to process that using JAVA. So, in Java program, I am initializing that as string and then will search on that text file. And then I will process....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialisation `String subString1 = "\"Notes\":[";` is correct as it initializes it with `"Notes":[`.

If you want to keep the `\`, you'll have to add an extra `\`:

`String subString1 = "\\\"Notes\\\":[";`

If you want to have an extra double quote at the end, you can also add it:

`String subString1 = "\\\"Notes\\\":[\"";`

This is because `\"` will result in `"` and `\\` will result in `\` So, `\\\"` will result in `\"`.

Comment: Yes I recognized (and updated) it.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Nexevis. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String subString1 = "\\\"Notes\\\":[\\\"";
        System.out.println(subString1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
\"Notes\":[\"
```

You need to escape `\` as well by using another `\`